# CSS Four Column width

Tags: html, css, list, multiple-columns

http://jsfiddle.net/YDLAJ/1/

Im having trouble with getting my list items to not overlap. My container width is 980px and the four columns line up correctly in the Jsfiddle example above but not on my site.

http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/manufacturers/

Here is the Html

```
<div style="width: 980px;">
<a href="http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/subzero-atlanta/"><img id="img-4-grid-1" alt="" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7353/10673034144_62c4da477b_o.jpg" /></a>

<a href="http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/thermador-atlanta/"><img id="img-4-grid" alt="" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7353/10673023936_5454b7b056_o.jpg" /></a>

<a href="http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/miele-atlanta/"><img id="img-4-grid" alt="" src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5524/10672964305_b80a36b1e0_o.jpg" /></a>

<a href="http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/kitchenaid-atlanta/"><img id="img-4-grid" alt="" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7400/10673024026_d1c2e8a43a_o.jpg" /></a>

<a href="http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/bosch-atlanta/"><img id="img-4-grid-1" alt="" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7396/10673034164_960a6e8e6d_o.jpg" /></a>

<a href="http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/bluestar-ranges-atlanta-2/"><img id="img-4-grid" alt="" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7293/10673023696_5f941a8f60_o.jpg" /></a>

<a href="http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/ge-appliances-atlanta-2/"><img id="img-4-grid" alt="" src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5490/10672964455_527d7519bf_o.jpg" /></a>

<a href="http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/wolf-atlanta-ranges/"><img id="img-4-grid" alt="" src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2873/10673023806_2452893531_o.jpg" /></a>

<a href="http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/asko-atlanta-appliances/"><img id="img-4-grid-1" alt="" src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5491/10672964445_88a6263b8d_o.jpg" /></a>

<a href="http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/danver-cabinets-atlanta/"><img id="img-4-grid" alt="" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7440/10673034704_a8f7dcd07a_o.jpg" /></a>

<a href="http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/elkay-sinks-atlanta/"><img id="img-4-grid" alt="" src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2860/10673024176_e2c6db268b_o.jpg" /></a>

<a href="http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/frigidaire-atlanta-appliances/"><img id="img-4-grid" alt="" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7419/10672964565_b3d8d01416_o.jpg" /></a>

<a href="http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/grohe"><img id="img-4-grid-1" alt="" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7327/10672964625_f7464e1018_o.jpg" /></a>

<a href="http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/hoshizaki-ice-machines-atlanta/"><img id="img-4-grid" alt="" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7411/10673024476_6422e33650_o.jpg" /></a>

<a href="http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/lynx-grill-atlanta/"><img id="img-4-grid" alt="" src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2865/10672964775_fed833543c_o.jpg" /></a>

<a href="http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/rohl-faucets-atlanta/"><img id="img-4-grid" alt="" src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2818/10672964805_6f7374f1be_o.jpg" /></a>

<a href="http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/scotsman-ice-machines-atlanta/"><img id="img-4-grid-1" alt="" src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3712/10672964895_6c5b430d7f_o.jpg" /></a>

<a href="http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/toto-toilets-atlanta/"><img id="img-4-grid" alt="" src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5480/10673023746_61fcea38de_o.jpg" /></a>

<a href="http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/u-line-atlanta/"><img id="img-4-grid" alt="" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7403/10673034434_b80a36b1e0_o.jpg" /></a>

<a href="http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/vent-a-hood-hoods-atlanta/"><img id="img-4-grid" alt="" src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2868/10673035064_29eb85aee6_o.jpg" /></a>

<a href="http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/viking-range-atlanta/"><img id="img-4-grid-1" alt="" src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3735/10673244223_88cda72243_o.jpg" /></a>

<a href="http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/whirlpool-appliances-atlanta/"><img id="img-4-grid" alt="" src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5544/10673035264_8e5fa564a1_o.jpg" /></a>

<a href="http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/zephyr-range-hood-atlanta/"><img id="img-4-grid" alt="" src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5513/10673025016_a08233e22d_o.jpg" /></a>

<a href="http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/grill-dome-grills-atlanta/"><img id="img-4-grid" alt="" src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2827/10673244513_07296f01a5_o.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
#img-4-grid-1 { 
width:237px; 
padding-bottom:10px;
float:left; 
}

#img-4-grid {
padding:0px 0px 10px 10px;
width:237px; 
float: left;
}
```

Comment: Don't use the same `id` for multiple elements. If you have more than one `img-4-grid`, it should be a `class`. Same goes for `img-4-grid-1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at bottom items, they are aligned perfectly. Problem is in your first item. In the first item, image comes inside an anchor tag. But the others have paragraph tag and then comes the anchor tag. Try doing the same thing to your first item.

Edit your first item code to this...

```
   <p><a href="http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/subzero-atlanta/"><img class="lazy data-lazy-ready" id="img-4-grid-1" alt="" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7353/10673034144_62c4da477b_o.jpg" data-lazy-type="image" data-lazy-src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7353/10673034144_62c4da477b_o.jpg" style="display: block;"><noscript>&lt;img id="img-4-grid-1" alt="" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7353/10673034144_62c4da477b_o.jpg" style="display: block;"></a></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the structure `<p>` → `<a>` → `<img>`. However you have one typo in your file where the `<a>` is outside your `<p>`. Put it inside your `<p>` and it should work. So:

```
<a href="http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/subzero-atlanta/">...</a>
<p></p>
```

to

```
<p>
   <a href="http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/subzero-atlanta/">...</a>
</p>
```

**Edit**

Here is the element i'm talking about:

[image]

The full path is:

[image]

`html` ▶ `body` ▶ `div#container` ▶ `div#wrapper-container` ▶ `div#wrapper` ▶ `div#content` ▶ `div#narrowcolumn` ▶ `div#post-26.post` ▶ `div.entry` ▶ `div`

Where a `#` represents a ID and a `.` a class.

Comment: The only thing within <p> is the paragraph. I've created a revised fiddle to display that. I do not know what you mean. http://jsfiddle.net/YDLAJ/2/

Answer (score 0):

In your `css`, under `.post .entry p img`, I deleted the rule `margin-bottom: 0;` and everything aligned perfectly on your site.

Comment: Deleting margin-bottom worked with "inspect element" but did not work once i deleted it from my actual css file